# Email Form more than 20 values

Tags: php, email

I have a form with more than 20 input fields. The PHP `mail` function is not working since it can only accept 5 parameters. How can I send these values to my email address?

Comment: What do you mean email only accepts five parameters?

Comment: The parameters in the mail() function have different meaning

Comment: Have you thought about using CC or BCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$to = 'myemail@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'form values';
$message = '';

foreach( $_POST as $key => $ value ) {
  $message .= $key . ' => ' . $value  . '<br>';
}

mail( $to, $subject, $message);
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters in the PHP mail() function have different meaning. They are not the data, sent to the user. Try using the following script and if it works - format the `$message` to match your requirements.

```
$email = 'rec@example.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$message = print_r($_POST,true);
mail($email,$subject,$message);
```

More information can be found @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know what kind of input fields you have, but they could all be passed in the "subject" field. However, if you have a sufficiently complex email to send, and you really need to write everything yourself, you should look into [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/docs).

So either add the 20 input fields onto the subject `$subject .= 20things` or use a tool that is inherently secure without having to remember to escape input and validate using regex.